# Extender for HAMAX child-bike-seat?

Tags: mountain-bike, child-seat

I just bought my wife an awesome [Merida Juliet](http://www.merida-bikes.com/en_int/bikes/hardtails/lady/2014/juliet-20-md-304.html).  But our (existing) [Hamax bike seat](http://www.hamax.com/child-bike-seat/classic-collection/siesta) doesn't fit over the tire when mounted to the frame (just touches the back wheel) and mounted on the seat post the metal rods go over the saddle.

Is there a hack or some kind of adapter that will let detachable bike seats fit on "compact" bike frames?

Comment: Did you ask the manufacturer to see if theres any alternatives for this? I'd be reluctant to mickey mouse the thing if a kid is involved.

Comment: I'm having trouble with their website but when I bought our siesta I'm sure they had more than one rail available.  It's implied by the "extra bar for adjustment" at www.hamax.com/child-bike-seat/accessories.  In fact googling *Hamax siesta extra bar* looks helpful.